# Typescript: How to use Enum to its full potential keeping the SOLID principles

Tags: angular, typescript

Coming from JAVA backgroud, I'm new to Angular and Typescript and want to code Front End as best as i can. Using Enum to populate my dropdown.

My Question, is it not possible to have both these functinalities,

1. Getting all values for the enum
2. Getting the string representation for label
   Defined in my `QuestionType.ts` file where the enum is define? so that don't have to write same method again on multiple places. Also easier to update at on place.

QuestionType.ts

```
export enum QuestionType {
  PLAIN_TEXT = 0,
  SINGLE_SELECT_OPTION = 1,
  MULTI_SELECT_OPTION = 2,
}
```

In my component class

```
export class QuestionFormComponent implements OnInit {
    
    // Loading all values for dropdown
    questionTypes = Object.values(QuestionType).filter(value => typeof value === 'number');
    
    // String representation for html label
    getTypeLabel(type: string | QuestionType) {
        if (typeof type === 'number') {
          switch (type) {
            case QuestionType.PLAIN_TEXT:
              return 'Plain Text';
            case QuestionType.SINGLE_SELECT_OPTION:
              return 'Single Selection';
            case QuestionType.MULTI_SELECT_OPTION:
              return 'Multi Selection';
            default:
              throw new Error('Unsupported option');
          }
        }
        return type; 
      }
    }
```

Form-html

```
    <div class="row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="questionType">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let queType of questionTypes" [value]="queType">
            {{ getTypeLabel(queType) }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="questionType?.invalid">You must make a selection</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

now lets say i've a list view that shows questions list with a column of type. Do i have to again put in same method here in List component calling basically same method from html

`````
        <ng-container matColumnDef="questionType">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Type</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ getTypeLabel(row.questionType) }}</td>
        </ng-container>````
`````

Comment: Make make a service and put `getTypeLabel` there. Alternatively, make it an exported free standing function

Comment: You could do as fujy suggests if you can change the numbers to strings. Otherwise, you can just map and return a string of values. Object.values(QuestionType).filter(value => typeof value === 'number').map(val => getTypeLabel(val)). This now returns the strings from your function and never has to call the getTypeLabel again. It's more performant as the function is not being called on every render.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no requirement to keep the enum values as numeric, you can use like below

```
export enum QuestionType {
  PLAIN_TEXT = 'PLAIN_TEXT',
  SINGLE_SELECT_OPTION = 'SINGLE_SELECT_OPTION',
  MULTI_SELECT_OPTION = 'MULTI_SELECT_OPTION',
}
```

And in your component, you can define your array of values similar to the way you did it

```
export class QuestionFormComponent {

  // Loading all values for dropdown
  questionTypes = Object.values(QuestionType)
  ...
}
```

And use it directly in your HTML template file

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let queType of questionTypes" [value]="questionType">
   {{ queType }}
 </mat-option>
```